# leaflet pop-up with JSON as text

Tags: leaflet

For debug purposes, I wanted my marker to have a pop-up that had the json in it.

The value is something like:

```
var CarState= {
    "height" : 6.2,
    "width" : 7.3,
    "length" : 9.1,
    "color" : {
        "r" : 255,
        "g" : 200,
        "b" : 10
    }
}
```

But this is not working, all I get is a truncated pop-up. The content of CarState is constantly changing, but the same property bag is there.

Notes: **self** refers to the AMD module that this code is in. I don't use this, since you can get in trouble. self.pop is a variable that holds the L.PopUp

```
this.update = function () {
    var text = "<p>" + JSON.stringify(CarState) + "</p>";
    self.pop.setContent(text);
    self.pop.update();
}
```

here is what it looks like:

[image]

and here is what Chrome says is the pop-up div size:

[image]

Comment: Please can you kindly clarify what are your `self` and `pop` variables? Note that you can directly update the content of a popup by using the marker method [`myMarker.setPopupContent()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setpopupcontent). The popup HTML is updated on next opening I think.

Comment: yeah a demo/fiddle would help in the solving of this.

Comment: But I am getting the lat/lon and rotation for a real device that is sending gps, so I cannot do a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is working for me now. Not completely sure what the problem was.

```
    this.update = function () {
        var text = "<pre><code>" + JSON.stringify(CarState, null, '\t') + "</code></pre>";
        theCar.setPopupContent(text);
        theCar.update();
        theCar.setLatLng(L.latLng(CarState.lat, CarState.lon));
        theMap.panTo(L.latLng(CarState.lat, CarState.lon));
    }
```